# Factory Girl with has many relationship (and a protected attribute)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-3, shoulda, factory-bot

I have this kind of relation:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  attr_protected :article_id
end
```

The default scenario inside controllers looks like:

```
@article = Article.create(:title => "foobar")
@comment = @article.comments.create(:content => "w00t")
```

I had tried to write those factories:

```
Factory.define :article do |f|
  f.title "Hello, world"
end

Factory.define :comment do |f|
  f.content "Awesome!"
  f.association :article
end
```

But my syntax is not correct about the association. It's a little bit tricky because of the comment's article_id protected attribute. So I think this should be better if I declare the association inside the article factory, but I don't see how to process.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do

```
Factory.define :comment do |f|
  f.content "Awesome!"
  f.article { |a| a.association(:article) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mb14. Happy RoR3 developments! :)