# Factory_girl has_one relation with validates_presence_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, factory-bot

I have 2 Models:

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
end

# profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user
end

# user_factory.rb
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.login "test"
  u.association :profile
end
```

I want to do this:

```
@user = Factory(:user)
=> #<User id: 88,....>
@user.profile
=> #<Profile id:123, user_id:88, ......>

@user = Factory.build(:user)
=> #<User id: nil,....>
@user.profile
=> #<Profile id:nil, user_id:nil, ......>
```

But this doesn't work!
It tells me that my profile model isn't correct because there is no user! (it saves the profile before the user, so there is no user_id...)

How can I fix this? Tried everything.. :(
And I need to call Factory.create(:user)...

**UPDATE**

Fixed this issue - working now with:

```
# user_factory.rb
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.profile { Factory.build(:profile)}
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :user
end

# profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user
end
```

Comment: I guess when you are 'created' the profile, it's saving it and so the user. Have you tried to 'build' the profile using Factory.build(:profile, :user =>a) in your factory ?

Comment: Yeah tried that, but didnt work... My "ugly" solution above works now... Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix it that way ([as explained in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634533/factory-girl-with-has-many-relationship-and-a-protected-attribute/3635012#3635012))

```
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.login "test"
  u.profile { |p| p.association(:profile) }
end
```

What you can do as well (as a user don't need a profile to exist (there's no validation on it) is to do a two steps construction

```
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.login "test"
end
```

and then

```
profile = Factory :profile
user = Factory :user, :profile => profile
```

I guess in that case you even just need one step, create the user in the profile factory and do

```
profile = Factory :profile
@user = profile.user
```

That seems the right way to do it, isn't it?

### Update

(according to your comment) To avoid saving the profile use Factory.build to only build it.

```
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.login "test"
  u.after_build { |a| Factory(:profile, :user => a)}    
end
```

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work, because the Profile becomes saved before the user... And so the validates_presence_of :user-validation won't accept saving... Fixed it with my solution above!

Comment: Ok, didn't see you answered your own post. That's weird anyway. We use factory girl a lot (where I work) and I've never seen this problem.

Comment: Ok... But my solution didn't work out in the end.. The User gets saved, even if i call Factoy.build(:user)... Dont know why... aaarghh Updated my post...

Comment: I'm confused... all works with "u.profile { Factory.build(:profile)}
", but not with your suggestion "u.profile { |p| p.association(:profile) }"... Crazy ^^

Comment: When you change your answer to my fix above, i will mark your answer as accepted... Thanks!