# has_one relation with validates_presence_of and the latest factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am facing the same problem as the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648699/factory-girl-has-one-relation-with-validates-presence-of). The post is quite outdated. I was wondering how to do the same thing. My factory is:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) {|n| "email#{n}@factory.com" }
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
    profile
  end
end
```

But `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` fails because of a validation error in the profile model with the user being blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to use the `after_create`. This ensures it only creates profile after it creates user.

```
factory :user do
    sequence(:email) {|n| "email#{n}@factory.com" }
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
    after_create do |user|
      FactoryGirl.create(:profile, :user => user)
    end
  end
```

You can call `Factory(:user)` afterward.